# What happens if I tap my hand at visible light frequencies?

Tags: visible-light, frequency

I have never taken a formal physics course, yet, so I apologize if my question is elementary.

I have seen electromagnetic charts where it shows a single digit Hz up to gamma rays etc each with their associated frequency range. My question is, what determines if something is light at a said frequency. For example, if I tap my hand at a visible light frequency my hand will not turn to light, at least I do not think so. If a frequency can be associated with a phenomenon like light or sound, that does not mean simply anything made to oscillate at that frequency will manifest itself into that phenomena.

So is there a chart that shows what materials will produce a specific thing like light at light frequencies?. Again I have no formal physics training, so if you can answer keeping that in mind. it would be of great service to me.

Comment: That's not what the frequency of a wave means. The frequency of a light wave is simply the rate of oscillation of the electromagnetic field that produces the wave. This frequency has nothing to do with the material medium (or lack thereof) or other physical characteristics of the wave -- for instance, you can have a sound wave and a light wave of the same frequency, it won't mean anything. You can't turn anything into light by shaking it around.

Comment: so if i light an LED with 5v a resistor to get 30mA , nevermind the color , where is this high frequency electromagnetic oscillation coming from? the LED material? surly not the DC supply...

Comment: The light comes from electrons in the semiconductor that the LED is made from. The electrons fall from a higher energy state to a lower energy state and emit a photon as they do so. It is not a mechanical process. There is no physical vibration involved.

Comment: @JohnRennie, What about a free electron laser? Does that not make light by "shaking" (i.e., accelerating) electrons?

Comment: “What will produce light at light frequencies?”  All of it is light.  It’s all photons.  I think you could have an interesting question somewhere in here, but it’s not getting votes and not coming across because it’s not explained clearly what you want to know.  Respectfully, I would suggest trying to rewrite it in a simple way, breaking it down to the basic assumptions and working up in steps.

Comment: @Lee What? There's no physically interesting question in asking "Is anything with a certain frequency the same as light with that frequency?" You can have light with zero frequency too (it's a static electromagnetic field), this is *not* the immediate result of "not shaking" something. I can't tell what interesting question you think the OP secretly meant.

Comment: I guess my question, or my confusion is Frequency being the common term in so many things, for example if you google "electromagnetic spectrum" all the images show charts that from left to right start at radio waves and then ultimately gamma rays and beyond... So I look at that and I wonder at what point does a radio wave turn into light (moving left to right on the chart) Do you just take the radio wave and oscillate it a lot faster. I just am very confused as to what oscillates  in light ... I tend to relate frequency with oscillations of physical things.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir actually I believe we may agree, except in my case it didn't really make sense to me what the question was trying to convey. In such cases I try to give the benefit of the doubt in that, if someone is curious, maybe there is something interesting, and maybe it's just not being communicated well, or even in an understandable way. Sometimes this approach helps me to balance a bias of cynicism.  But of course, I also allow for the possibility it could just be nonsensical thinking.

Comment: @EdwinFairchild *at what point does a radio wave turn into light* radio waves *are* light, so i'm not sure what you mean here?

Comment: @Edwin, Yeah, and an electromagnetic field is a physical thing. So for instance, visible light is simply a faster oscillation of it than a radio wave.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The frequency of visible light is about $500\times10^{12}$Hz, five hundred trillion oscillations per second. I believe that if you could tap your hand at this frequency, it would give off visible light, as well as disintegrating. It would be very hard indeed to oscillate any macroscopic body at that frequency though. I don't believe that such technology exists. All of the common kinds of visible light such as incandescent light bulbs, LEDs, fluorescent tubes, and sunlight are given off by the motions of microscopic charged particles called electrons rather than by macroscopic moving bodies.