# Hypothetically, would tapping one's hand, or otherwise vibrating a physical object, at the frequency of visible light produce light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

This was inspired by the following just-closed question:

[What happens if I tap my hand at visible light frequencies?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414245)

We know that sound can be and is produced by a vibrating object if it is in contact with a suitable medium such as air, since the rapid, back-and-forth motion of such an object sets up waves in that medium - typically longitudinal, compression waves, given that it is pushing against the medium repeatedly and when you push into something, you compress it slightly.

Yet we also know that in a way, an object, at least one made of ordinary matter, is in "contact" with the electromagnetic field: in particular, it is composed of charged particles like electrons and protons that are electromagnetically reactive, which is why that objects are able to reflect and absorb light rays. Moreover, warm objects emit thermal electromagnetic radiation due to the random motions of their constituent charged particles.

Following that insight, would it be reasonable to suppose that, hypothetically, were there a way to physically vibrate the object, so that it moves back and forth, at a frequency equal to that of visible light, say 500 THz, perhaps at suitably small amplitude so as not to be damaged, would it then emit visible light at that frequency in analogy with how that a lower-frequency vibration in contact with air emits sound at the given frequency? More generally, what are the physical factors that determine what, if any, kind of radiation will be emitted by the vibration of an object?

Argument in favor of light emission:

- While the overall object is charge neutral, to treat it as having zero electromagnetic interactivity is only an approximation that holds suitably far outside the object: get very close - within atomic dimensions - to the surface and you start to "see" the electrons and nuclei separately and now begin feeling a field. This field may fall off fast with distance, but it does not go to zero. In theory that should result in some low amplitude wave, or photons released with low but still nonzero probability, since an imaginary infinite sensitivity detector could pick up the minute changes as the object moves closer and further away during vibration, which is information being transmitted, and that means radiation must be occurring.

Argument against light emission:

- Thermal emission requires particles moving up and down in quantum energy levels within the material. From a naive classical mechanics pov this is equivalent to things like increasing and decreasing distances *between an electron and the nucleus it is attached to*. That is, the separation between the alternate charges in the material does not oscillate when the whole thing is in coherent motion. Thus it is not reasonable to argue from the existence of thermal radiation that light will be emitted in a scenario like this.

Comment: May need to rephrase your question--re. 'opinion based'.  Maybe just repeat the title.

Comment: @user45664 : I don't understand what you are asking for. Are you suggesting to make the question body simply a repetition of the question title? That would seem to be extremely unhelpful to any readers. Please clarify this matter.

Comment: Right now your question is "What do you think?".  I was suggesting making it more specific rather than being broadly opinion based.

Comment: @user45664 - Nixed.

Comment: What makes you think it might be possible to tap your hand at a frequency of 500THz?

Comment: @sammy gerbil : That's why it's called a "hypothetical".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do composite particles that are electrically neutral but have charged constituents radiate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30547/do-composite-particles-that-are-electrically-neutral-but-have-charged-constituen)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, in some materials. For example, see [Theoretical Study of the Emission of Light Stimulated by Phonons in Indirect Bandgap Semiconductor](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050911006326).  But most [optical phonons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon#Acoustic_and_optical_phonons) will not result in measurable optical emission.